# jQuery show/hide not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some trouble with showing/hiding LI elements in a list using jQuery, here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.news").find("li.hidden").hide();

    $("ul.news a.show").click(function() {
        $("ul.news").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.news").find("li.hide").show();
    });

    $("ul.news a.hide").click(function() {
        $("ul.news").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.news").find("li.show").show();
    });



    $("ul.articles").find("li.hidden").hide();

    $("ul.articles a.show").click(function() {
        $("ul.articles").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.articles").find("li.hide").show();
    });

    $("ul.articles a.hide").click(function() {
        $("ul.articles").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.articles").find("li.show").show();
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<h3 class="gray-default">Press Releases</h3>
<ul class="news-landing news span8">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="show"> <a class="view-more show">To view more &gt;&gt;</a> </li>
    <li class="hide"> <a class="view-more hide">To view less &gt;&gt;</a> </li>
</ul>

<h3 class="gray-default">Articles &amp; Reports</h3>
<ul class="news-landing articles span8">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="" target="_blank">xxx</a></li>
    <li class="show"> <a class="view-more show">To view more &gt;&gt;</a> </li>
    <li class="hide"> <a class="view-more hide">To view less &gt;&gt;</a> </li>
</ul>
```

But what is happening:

- on the initial page load everything appears fine, only 3 items in each list and the correct 'view more" link
- click view more under news & the list expand correctly, but both more and less links are visible, clicking either link will collapse the list, but both links are visible.
- click view more under articles & the list expands, but only the view more link is visible, clicking it again collapses the list, and the more link is still visible. the less link never appears.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Actually you can get rid of all (most) your code by using CSS styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually hide the show more / show less links at the appropriate time in your code. Try updating your JavaScript as follows (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cJV5/1/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.news").find("li.hidden").hide();
    $("ul.news").find("li.hide").hide(); // hide the hide button by default

    $("ul.news li.show").click(function() {
        $(this).hide(); // hide the show button
        $("ul.news").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.news").find("li.hide").show(); // and show the hide button
    });

    $("ul.news li.hide").click(function() {
        $(this).hide(); // hide the hide button 
        $("ul.news").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.news").find("li.show").show(); // and show the show button
    });



    $("ul.articles").find("li.hidden").hide();
    $("ul.articles").find("li.hide").hide();

    $("ul.articles li.show").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("ul.articles").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.articles").find("li.hide").show();
    });

    $("ul.articles li.hide").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("ul.articles").find("li.hidden").toggle();
        $("ul.articles").find("li.show").show();
    });
});
```

You could refactor this to avoid the code duplication, but I think it's probably a good start.

Comment: @Charlietfl's answer looks far more elegant. Probably worth dissecting.

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh. Sure, there are better answers than this, but I have fixed the original problem.

Comment: Downvoting without putting a comment sucks, something I think SO should address.

Answer (score 2):

Can simplify the whole thing and remove code repetition with:

CSS:

```
.hidden,li.hide{display:none}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.show,li.hide').click(function(){
        $(this).toggle().siblings('.hide,.hidden,.show').toggle();      
    });
})
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KZHQm/)</kbd>

By using `siblings()` you keep the DOM search isolated within each `UL` and therefore don't need to specify different handlers for each set of controls

Comment: really sad but I recently found out that *button-alike* links are not welcome in the community any more `;(` "sigh"

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyebud/4/edit)**

**Simplify your HTML:**

```
<h3 class="gray-default">Press Releases</h3>
<ul class="news-landing span8">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx0</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx4</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx5</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">xxx6</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="news-landing-toggle"></a>
```

and here's your super-simple jQuery:

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  var btnTxt = ["View more", "View less"];
  $('.news-landing').find('li:gt(2)').hide();

  $(".news-landing-toggle").click(function( e ) {

      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).text( btnTxt.reverse()[0] ).prev('ul').find('li:gt(2)').slideToggle();    

  }).text( btnTxt[0] );

});
```

---

Another solution using a bit more of **CSS** would be:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyebud/5/edit)**

```
.news-landing li:nth-child(n+4){
  display:none;
}
.news-landing + .news-landing-toggle:after{
  content:"View more";
}
.news-landing.opened li:nth-child(n+4){
  display:inherit;
}
.news-landing.opened + .news-landing-toggle:after{
  content:"View Less";
}
```

jQ:

```
$('.news-landing-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev('ul').toggleClass('opened');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, instead of using `toggle()`, don't you want to use `show()` and `hide()`?

That is, when you click <kbd>view more</kbd>, you would use `show()` and when you click <kbd>view less</kbd> you use `hide()`.

Additionally, when you click <kbd>view more</kbd>, you need to `hide()` the <kbd>Show more</kbd> link and `show()` the <kbd>View less</kbd> link and vice versa.